# n-Tier Architecture in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, architecture

It is said in a book that n-Tier Architecture is combination of 2-Tier and 3-Tier Architectures. But it seems to be same as 3-Tier Architecture. Kindly clarify this doubt.

Comment: It means more than 3 tiers, like 4 or 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In n-tier architecture the layers can be virtually distributed into various segments. For example,the business logic layers has been divided into various segments such as business model, business rules, and business object to data source mapping. In three tier architecture, the business logic layer resides at a single location; however, in n tier it is categorized into further segments”

Answer (score 1):

`n` is wildcard here, `n` could be 2 (or) 3 (or) more (generally n will be used to say more than 3). Nowadays, "service" layer is the new one introduced on top of MVC (Which is good example of n-tier). Here is one example [SO discussion about Service layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702391/mvcs-model-view-controller-service).

Comment: I don't think the question here is about service layer.

Comment: @Pavan608: It is about what, then?

Comment: In n-tier architecture the layers can be virtually distributed into various segments. For example,the business logic layers has been divided into various segments such as business model, business rules, and business object to data source mapping. In three tier architecture, the business logic layer resides at a single location; however, in n tier it is categorized into further segments”

Comment: The question is: What is the difference between 3-tier and n-tier architectures. When i studied a topic initially i can't understand the difference between them and both looks to be same for me. Then i mailed to publishers and they answered it as above. I am satisfied with that.

Comment: 2-tier and 3-tier (and onwards) are n-tier. Your answer seems to conflate MVC with n-tier, which are unrelated concepts.

Comment: @HenryCollingridge interesting, how MVC is not n-tier and which tier category it falls into? If you are saying 2 & 3 or not n-tier, but only 4 onwards are n-tier based on Pavan answer (and some publisher said), I don't agree because, in MVC implementation you can distribute business logic layer without using "services" approach. So, I interpret 'n' as pure how many layers involved in implementation rather than giving it discrete distinctions to make it more complicated. If you don't agree I respect your opinion.