# How to preserve the MVC methodology using Appcelerator's Modules

Tags: model-view-controller, module, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I'm using alloy on titanium, I want to use modules but I'm worried about breaking the MVC principles.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: IMO, MVC is used to separate your Model, View and controller logic. But as this logic is already implemented in a module you have no control over its implementation. What you have is some methods which you have to use. Consider google analytic module you have to just call a method to use it. You have no control over the implementation. So I think you are not breaking MVC pattern if using module.

Answer (score 1):

In our projects we are using Titanium modules as service layer. (If  a piece of business logic will be used in more than one controller, we refactor the logic into a module, so logic can be injected in all controllers). I do not see any violations of the original MVC architecture.

What we're trying to achieve in our projects is close to MVCS architecture ([more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702391/mvcs-model-view-controller-service))