# How to pass data from one API request to another with Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, http-proxy

I have a working sample however I am sure it can be refactored for improvement. The project is a Weather app built with React, Node/Express and [OpenWeather API](https://openweathermap.org/).  Basically the `lat` and `lon` values from first API response are needed as params in second API request. Reason for having Node server is to hide API key in browser. :)

Here is a breakdown of folder structure(only includes relevant files):

**weather-app/**
  ...
  **src/**
    **hooks/**
    useForecast.js
  ...
  index.js
  **routes/**
    weather.js
    onecall.js

Here are the breakdown of each file(only includes relevant codes):

**index.js(express entry file):**

```
app.use('/weather', require('./routes/weather'))
app.use('/onecall', require('./routes/onecall'))
```

**weather.js(1st API call):**

```
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => { 
  try {
    const params = new URLSearchParams({
      ...url.parse(req.url, true).query, //location value from useForecast.js 
      appid: API_KEY
    })

    const apiRes = await needle('get', `${BASE_URL}/weather?${params}`) //api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=somecity&appid={API_KEY}
    const data = apiRes.body //data will be used in useForecast.js

    res.status(200).json(data)
  } catch(error) {
    next(error)
  }
})
```

**onecall.js(2nd API call):**

```
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const params = new URLSearchParams({
      ...url.parse(req.url, true).query, //lat and lat value from useForecast.js
      appid: API_KEY 
    })

    const apiRes = await needle('get', `${BASE_URL}/onecall?${params}`) //api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={API_KEY}
    const data = apiRes.body //data will be used in useForecast.js

    res.status(200).json(data)
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
})
```

**useForecast.js(hook call from React):**

```
const useForecast = () => {
  ...    
  const getCoordinates = async location => {   
    const { data } = await axios(`/weather?q=${location.value}`) //url from weather.js

    if(data.cod === '404' || !data) {
      setError(data.message)
      setLoading(false)
      return
    }

    return data
  }

  const getForecastData = async (lat, lon) => {
    const { data } = await axios(`/onecall?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}`) //url from onecall.js

    if(data.cod === '400' || !data) {
      setError('something went wrong')
      setLoading(false)
      return
    }

    return data
  }     
 ... 
}
```

Can both calls in **weather.js** and **onecall.js** be refactored and combined into one? If so would changes in **useForecast.js** have to be made also?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it using a architecture pattern similar to [MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6216013/3957754) or [MVCS](https://github.com/SamuelAsherRivello/UMVCS#mvcs)

#### MVCS

Used in server side rendering applications or in a simple terms: **used in previous generation webs (java, python, php, etc)**. Modern webs(react, angular, vue, etc) don't use this. Basically in this pattern you have this structure:

[image]

- V means **View** : html, templates, etc
- C means **Controller** : server side in charge of return just data like json,xml,etc or view merged it with data (https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html)
- S means **Service**: implements the logic. Controller uses one of several services to orchestrate the operation
- M means **Model**: abstraction of the database or datasource to be read or write.

#### MSR

I don't know if I'm creating this , but is the same as MVCS but for apis or microservices in which views or pages don't exist:

- R means **Rest controller**. Route in yous nodejs case
- S means **Service**. Javascript class or module with logic. Rest controller uses one of several services to orchestrate the operation
- M means **Model**: abstraction of the database, external apis or any datasource (file, etc) to be read or write.

[image]

#### Model-Service-Rest in nodejs

**Service.js with logic**

```
const Service = () => {

  this.getCoordinates = async function(location){
    try {
      const params = new URLSearchParams({
        q:location, 
        appid: API_KEY
      })

      const apiRes = await needle('get', `${BASE_URL}/weather?${params}`) //api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=somecity&appid={API_KEY}
      const data = apiRes.body 
      return data;
    } catch(error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  this.getForecastData = async function(lat, lon){
    try {
      const params = new URLSearchParams({
        lat:lat,
        lon:lon,
        appid: API_KEY
      })

      const apiRes = await needle('get', `${BASE_URL}/weather?${params}`) //api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=somecity&appid={API_KEY}
      const data = apiRes.body
      return data;
    } catch(error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
  
}
```

**Routes.js**

```
router.get('/forecast-data', async (req, res, next) => { 
  var coordinates = await this.service.getCoordinates(req.query.q);
  var forecastData = await this.service.getForecastData(req.query.lat, req.query.lon);
  res.status(200).json(forecastData)
})
```

If another web required only the coordinates, you could re-use the service

```
router.get('/coordinates', async (req, res, next) => { 
  var coordinates = await this.service.getCoordinates(req.query.q);
  res.status(200).json(coordinates)
})
```

Comment: @JRichardz thanks for the suggestions. Will give it a try.